# Converting css to less

Tags: css, less

I am trying to convert some css to less, but on compile i got some errors?
Here is what i have in css, how to convert this to less

```
#preloader {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #2AABE2;
    background: rgba(42, 171, 226, 0.5);
    display: none;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.80;
    opacity: 0.80;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha"(Opacity=60);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=60);
    filter:alpha(opacity=60);
    z-index: 20000;
    text-align: center;
}
.preloader-text {
    color: white;
    font-size:16px !important;
    margin: auto auto 10px;
}
.preloader-holder {
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 200px;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -100px 0 0 -200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 400px;
}
```

Comment: You should be able to leave it the way it is. CSS is valid LESS

Comment: Of course but this is IE8 fix and i have bundle, that is problem

Comment: The problem i have is with   -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha"(Opacity=60);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=60);
    filter:alpha(opacity=60);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use [escape character](http://lesscss.org/functions/#string-functions-escape) `~`:

```
#preloader {
    ....
    -ms-filter:~'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha"(Opacity=60)';
    filter: ~'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=60)';
    ....
}
```

remember to use single quotes to contain entire string, because value already containd double ones.

Answer (score 0):

Try prefixing the string with ~

```
-ms-filter: ~"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=60)";
```

or

```
-ms-filter: e("progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=60)");
```

Check out [string functions on less docs](http://lesscss.org/functions/#string-functions-e)